# What does Category's attribute is_anchor do?

Tags: category, certification

I'm doing some sample tests from Magento 2 certification. There's this question (screenshot) I don't understand.

[image]

The correct answer for this question is A "This is the default category for a website", but according to my knowledge (I have been working with Magento for many years), if we turn **Anchor** on for a category, it's just enable the ***layered navigation*** for this category.

I wonder why the correct answer is"This is the default category for a website" when is_anchor is set to 1? can someone please explain?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That looks like an issue with the test question to me.

I would have thought the correct answer should be option 2:

> ```
> The customer will see all products from all the children of the category
> ```

If **is_anchor = yes**, all the products for the current category and all children categories display, along with the layered navigation if filterable attributes are setup allowing you to filter the products.

Comment: you are right, the correct Answer is actually 2, they have just updated the question.

Comment: wondering if this kind of functions/behavior should be explicitly and easily found on the official documentation, I cannot see anything else than the layered search in this case.